# Don't forget we have Chat!

Tags: discussion, chat

I've noticed something with [certain questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1213/should-i-terminate-my-contract) of ours. [These questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/should-i-consider-emigration-for-better-career), while certainly "real problems", are generally too localized or not constructive as questions, so we can't really leave them open. They might be interesting discussions, but they're probably not going to be helpful to others searching for similar, but different, situations. Questions need answers that are applicable to a broad audience.

Common symptoms include extended **comment discussions** and the asker **already knowing what they need to do**. Comments being used like that [is a bad sign](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not); questions are not for "advice" or reassurance so much as solutions. However, we have a great platform for simple advice, reassurance or just sharing war stories: **Chat**.

**We have [a lovely Chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) for everyone to discuss matters serious or trivial.** Don't forget about it, there's a link at the top of every page on The Workplace and Meta as well. If you have at least **20 reputation** you're allowed to talk in chat (even without 20 rep you can *read* chat).

If you're trying to work out a problem but you don't think it quite matches the quality standards in our [FAQ](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), consider asking in Chat. We can bounce back ideas, give some advice or help you phrase your question constructively.

Answer (score -5):

Don't you think the chat room is kinda messy?

1) Basically anyone can speak in the middle of a conversation of 2 guys and bring up new topic which is not relevant to the existing topic.

2) The bot which remind us of new questions is disturbing.

3) We need to press the tiny little "chat" button to enter, and it doesn't stand out between the other button such as "about"/"meta"/"faq".

4) The last time with a people speaking is 5 hours ago. This looks like ghost town to me.

Comment: It's a chat. Chat is messy.  As to your questions about how chat works, those questions/comments should go to [Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) as it's an SE-wide function.

Comment: Too noisy and ghost town in the same list... Heh. It's worth noting that if you're trying to have a focused discussion between 2 (or more) people, you can easily create a new room and invite folks into it for that purpose. But when there's not much going on, hanging out in a communal area generally isn't too confusing.