# Community moderation comments template

Tags: support, faq, comments, moderation

#### AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for *Workplace SE*

[CMW](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/10912/cmw) asked for a list of the links that we oftentimes drop in comments. I started using the [Pro-forma comments Stack Apps script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) to increase my efficiency.

I find that I almost never use the defaults that come with the script and that I rely entirely on my own tailored versions that use my personal wording and style. I also tend to insert them into the comment box and then tailor it to the situation. Every person is different and every post is different, and we don't need robots to deal with people, we need *people* to help other people succeed.

**Import/Export markup:**

Highlight the content in the box below and paste into the import/export section of the Pro forma comments modal window. Edit the comments to tailor to your own style, then save:

```
###Comments as answers
Comments are intended to help improve a post or seek clarification. Please don't answer the questions in the comments. These can't be easily voted on as the best answers, and they may inadvertently prevent other users  from providing real answers. Please see [How should I post a useful non-answer if it shouldn't be a comment?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1866/98) for more guidance.

###Comments as answers 2
Please don't use comments to answer questions as this may prevent others from providing full, complete answers that the community would vote on. Please see [How should I post a useful non-answer if it shouldn't be a comment?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1866/98) for more guidance.

###Back it up rule
Hello and welcome to The Workplace SE. Our Q&A site put in place some [back it up](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/123/should-we-add-a-back-it-up-rule-to-the-faq-now) guidelines to help get the best answers. Can you [edit] your post to include references or relate this to a personal experience. Also, be sure to answer the full question. Good luck! :)

###Chatty comments
Please avoid using comments for extended discussion. Instead, please use [chat]. On Workplace SE, comments are intended to help improve a post. Please see [What "comments" are not...](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) for more details.

###Insufficient explanation
Hello user, welcome to The Workplace. On our site, we're looking for answers with some depth that explain *why* and *how*. Our goal is to build a library of knowledge for navigating the professional workplace. Please consider an [edit] to expand, and be sure to answer the full question. See [answer] for details.

###Deleting answer
On The Workplace, we're looking for answers with some depth that explain *why* and *how* and that are ideally backed by facts, references, and personal experiences. Please see [Why and how are some answers deleted](http://$SITEURL$/help/deleted-answers) and [How do I write a good answer](http://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-answer), as well as [The back it up rule](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others) for more details.

###Polling questions
Hello, welcome to The Workplace, a Stack Exchange Q&A site. Chatty, open-ended questions tend to not work out so well on our site, since almost every answer will  be correct and we can't as easily vote on them to rank the best answers. Instead, ask questions about a real, actual problem you're facing, which includes plenty of details so answers are more targeted. For more details, please see [ask] and [about]. Good luck!

###Quit your job
Hello! On The Workplace, our site's goal is to build a professional library of knowledge for future visitors who have problems navigating the workplace. Advising someone to quit their job is a *big move;* as a result, we hold these answers to a higher standard. Please consider an [edit] to your post to meet our site's [back it up](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/255/98) guidelines, and also see [Is 'quit your job' an acceptable answer](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1697/98). Good luck.

###Closing question that could be reopened
Hello, we put your post on hold to give you time to clarify it via an [edit]. When you edit your post, it gets pushed back into a [review queue](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) where the community can [work together to get the post reopened](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions). Hope this helps.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: Thanks Jmort!  This is very helpful

Answer (score 9):

## General Stack Exchange moderation resources for *Workplace SE*

Here are some resources that help make Workplace SE easier to use.

#### Stack Apps browser add-ons:

- [AutoReviewComments Stack Exchange Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

#### Blog articles:

- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) describes the theory behind community moderation and helps put high rep users and moderators in the right mindset. Keep in mind that it's designed to be a guide, not a rule, and many people will interpret this in different ways.
- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) outlines six subjective guidelines to good subjective questions. It's also a precursor to [The Workplace's back it up guidelines](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others). It's not just questions that should follow the six guidelines. Answers should approach every question with those goals in mind.
- [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) picks up where Good subjective, Bad Subjective leaves off and digs a little deeper into the subject, going as far as suggesting that some questions that appear to be polling questions may not actually be polling questions. The key is to ask if the question is about a real, actual problem. Also, look at the answers and ask if they follow the six guidelines.

  > **real questions have *answers*, not *items* or *ideas* or *opinions*.**

#### Workplace SE Meta posts:

- [What comments are not...](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) is an official response from the Stack Exchange community team regarding how they view comments.
- [Back it up rule](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others) contains the official [help center text](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that outlines what our community expects answers to contain. Answers that follow these guidelines generally also meet the six subjective guidelines.