# Does this question fall under "What job should I take"?

Tags: discussion

[Quitting a company that recently had an IPO](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23996/quitting-a-company-that-recently-had-an-ipo)

It seems to me this is just another flavor of "What job should I take?" questions.

Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think it is. I have closed it for now, though I invite the community to take a look at it and see if there are any edits on it.

When you see an off-topic post like this from a new user, I encourage the community to leave information explaining this to the user to act as a guide for how they can improve the post. On this one, I left the following comment pointing them to resources to figure out what our guidelines are, which ones their post doesn't follow, and inviting them to improve their post:

> Hey DotnetDude, and welcome to [workplace.se]. As explained in our [about] page, we're a bit different from other sites. Questions here should focus on practical answerable questions based on actual problems you face as described in our [help/dont-ask]. As explained in our [help/on-topic], questions asking for career advice are off-topic here. If you can [edit] your question to make it more general and applicable without asking for guidance, it will automatically be reviewed by the community. Thanks in advance!

If you are willing to take a few minutes to install the [pro forma comments script](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2439/community-moderation-comments-template) that jmort uses, making these comments won't take much effort on your part and can make it quick and easy to add these comments yourself.

When moderating the site, the most pleasant surprise I get is a great informative comment explaining our guidelines here and inviting the person to the community. It makes our job much easier, and puts forward a good message from our community about our standards, and the SE concept of community moderation.

Thanks for bringing this up here -- meta posts discussing questions like this are good to help us figure out what content we want, and help raise community awareness of the types of issues we face. Keep up the good work!

Comment: I agree.  The guy knows the downsides of switching and potential benefits of it.  There is little that this site can offer him in terms of a fact based good subjective complete answer.  Even if it wasn't off topic it should be closed for opinion based.