# Why does this site support political censorship and editorializing?

Tags: discussion

I downvoted this question:

> [What are tools/resources I can use to check a company for transphobia
>   and sexism during a job
>   search?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27403/what-are-tools-resources-i-can-use-to-check-a-company-for-transphobia-and-sexism)

After downvoting, I was prompted to add a comment explaining my reasons, which were that I found the language of the question  - "sexist" and "transphobia" - and "*really*" unnecessarily provocative - bordering on rant: Not everyone who doesn't want to deal with TG's can or should be characterized using such loaded terminlogy. Neutral language would have sufficed for the question.

My comment apparenly ruffled the feathers of others for PC reasons. The language of the question was allowed to stand, but my comment was deleted. Such actions amount to inapproprate political censorship. If this is a site for professionals to exchange information,  questions should be written in a neutral,  adult fashion, not used as a platform for promoting political agendas and rants.

I also edited the question and replaced the  provocative language with language that was neutral but did not in any way distort the intent of the question. My edits were also rejected. Again, it appears that there are those on this site that are more interested in promoting a particular political agenda than discussing workplace issues in a professional manner.

IMO this site loses a great deal of its credibility through such behavior and policy. Why is this allowed and condoned?

*(It also appears that I have been subject to a rash of serial downvoting as the result of my remarks, perhaps by more than one member. )*

Comment: It should be noted that it was the original poster that declined both your edits, and in most cases regarding minor edits such as this the OP is allowed to keep his/her question the way they want providing it is within the site's guidelines. If you feel offended with the language used in the question, please feel free to leave a polite comment and it will get upvotes if others agree, however if the wording is not meant to be offensive and no one else sees a problem with it, then it's left to the OP if they want to edit their post or not.

Comment: @Rachel - they were far more than minor edits qualitatively. In the end I also left a polite but quite articulate comment, which one of mods felt duty bound to remove. This is inappropriate.

Comment: And someone else downvotes this question also. Is this entire subject **taboo**?

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, however I felt like the [edits](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18631) [suggested](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18632) were pretty minor, and may have actually made the question less clear.

Comment: In addition, the edit comment you included with the edits might have been perceived the wrong way by the OP, especially if you had already downvoted and left a comment using similar terms on their question, and they explained their reason for rejecting your edit suggestion as well: *"Transphobia and sexism are real problems. It is not a "rant" to use specific, applicable, descriptive language"*

Comment: Caveat - I was tempted to upvote this question just reading the title...  then I read the question.  So you editorialized and showed political bias in a non constructive comment.  Now you are whining because that comment was deleted and you are blaming it on political bias and censorship...  I recommend you consider Reddit for your future posting needs.  They seem more your speed and maturity level.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just sour grapes not an actual question

Comment: "Not everyone who doesn't want to deal with TG's can or should be characterized using such loaded terminlogy."  I **completely** disagree, doubly so in a workplace context.  There's no legitimate reason whatsoever for an employer to care if an employee is transgendered, gay, or anything else.  The people and employers who do _deserve_ to be called out and ostracized for it.

Comment: @aroth - **I completely and utterly disagree**. (Am I right now?)

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame - no I removed political bias. My edits made the post neutral. I guess to you, neutral means whatever you agree with and biased means whatever you don't agree with...

Comment: @Rachel:   [**Transphobia**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/transphobia) : _Intense dislike of or prejudice against transsexual or transgender people_ . What proof do you have that those people mentioned who don't wish to hire TG's are motivated by "intense dislike and prejudice"? **NONE.** It is a pejorative term.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame - I am **really tired** of people who find certain subjects taboo and therefore dismiss discussion regarding them as "sour grapes". Perhaps you're the one whose "grapes" are "soured"?

Comment: @Rachel - _may have actually made the question less clear_ : Please explain how those edits made the question less clear? The question asked about resources for the subject of bias in TG hiring and how to avoid it. My edits in no way made that question any less clear - they simply removed pejorative and provocative language that was entirely irrelevant to the question itself, but constituted what bordered on a rant on the part of the OP.

Comment: @aroth - _deserve to be called out and ostracized for it_ - so you advocate the Joe McCarthy policy for handling this? Blacklisting? How about the pillory, or an old fashioned lynching, since we're going "old school" here? I thought we were more **tolerant** these days? Or does that only include tolerating views that you yourself subscribe to...?

Comment: @moderators : Note - **do not accuse me of being "not nice" here.** Take care to note that I have simply responded to comments in the manner in which they were expressed. If my responses are "not nice", neither are those comments. Am I expected to accept absurd and insulting comments simply because they pass your muster of "political correctness"? A great person once said ""I disapprove of what you say, but I will defend to the death your right to say it". Take that lesson and run with it.

Comment: @Vector I read the question as *"How can I find out if a company has a problematic culture with regards to sexism and transphobia"*, as opposed to your edits which to me made it sound like *"How can I find out if a company has any problems with me being a transgender"*, or with *"gender related problems"*. To me, those are slightly different questions and personally I prefer the original version of the question. The words "sexism" and "transphobia" are meant to describe negative traits, not people. They are very real issues in the world, and I see no problem using such words in this context.

Comment: @Vector - I advocate being intolerant of prejudice, bigotry, and intolerance.  In my view 'tolerance' applies to those things that a person cannot choose; their race, age, gender, sexual orientation, etc..  You can't fault a person for those things, because they had no say in the matter.  However, "not wanting to deal with TG's (or women, or hispanics, or whatever)" is a _choice_, one that's invariably based upon invalid and spurious reasons.  I don't believe people are entitled to make foolish choices and then hide under the umbrella of 'tolerance' to escape criticism and consequences.

Answer (score 12):

The comments were not removed because of 'political censorship', they were removed because [comments are not for debate or discussion](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not). If you do not want comments to be removed, take care to [be nice](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and keep in mind [the purpose of comments](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

If you feel that the words 'sexism' or 'transphobia' are politically charged, then the proper course of action is to bring them up as questions on meta for the community to weigh in on. If you want to avoid 'political censorship' then I strongly believe that trying to force edits to posts without any sort of discussion or input from the community is the absolutely wrong way act. And discussing them in comments is just not the appropriate place for that.

Comment: The question about finding a workaround for serial downvoting was not a duplicate.

Comment: _take care to be nice_ : The post I edited was "not nice" - the language it used was pejorative - gratuitous and judgmental with no supporting evidence. I simply explained that such was the case. If the post is "nice", so were my comments.

Comment: Your categorization of my comments as "not nice" while accepting the post itself as "nice" reflects a serious bias on your part as moderator - hardly appropriate.

Comment: This is an answer to anyone with the same issue in the future @Vector. Comments that do not fit the guidelines, and/or comments that are not nice will be removed. That goes for everyone and is not intended as a specific jab toward you.