# Why was this comment on the handshake question deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

In the question [How does one politely decline a handshake due to religious reasons?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/46611/how-to-politely-decline-a-handshake-due-to-religious-reasons) , I wrote the comment

> This question should be migrated to Islam.SE

It has been deleted.

Why was this deleted?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289949/prevent-im-voting-to-close-this-because-it-belongs-on-custom-close-reasons#comment175406_289949

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with your comment. It's just that, there were a lot of them, and some of them were quite nasty and not keeping with the spirit of Stack Exchange's [be nice](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy. Other comments simply intended to *discuss* or *debate* the issue, which again is not the goal of our site.  Since the purpose of our site is to answer questions, not convey our opinions, a moderator deleted most of the comments in order to keep the focus on the Q&A.

Again, there's nothing wrong with your comment, but sometimes innocuous comments get caught up in the deletion task. We try to look at each one, but sometimes that isn't possible or we make mistakes.  [Comments aren't designed to be a place to store valuable information](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/72/98), so when it comes to comments, if in doubt, we'll delete. Don't take this the wrong way.

As for the migration request, I'd say this could likely fit Islam SE, but it also seems on topic here on Workplace SE, since it's a question about how to handle colleagues in the workplace where personal religious beliefs play a part. As a general rule, if a question is on topic on this site, our first loyalty as Workplace SE members is to this site, we don't migrate questions just because they *might* be on topic on another site. See [Respect the community -- your own, and others'](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) for details:

> **Respecting your own community**
>
> As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to *that* community. When evaluating a question, you shouldn’t be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. ***Be a bit jealous of your site*** – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it – and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.

Comment: Upon further review,  might you be able to restore the comment? Or would you recommend that the OP repost it?

Comment: @JimG. - There's no community migration path to Islam SE, and this isn't a question we would migrate because it seems to fit Workplace SE, so reposting the comment would be unnecessary.