# Where did the comments go?

Tags: discussion, bug, comments

There were a bunch of comments on [Should my manager be aware of private LinkedIn approaches I receive? How to politely have this happen?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/138828/26998). A seemingly random bunch of them were deleted. There is no "moved to chat" comment, and some of them survived the purge. The remaining comments have now lost context. What happened?

EDIT:  This question was not a dupe, because the deleted comment did not follow any of the deletion rules.  They were seemingly at random.  But since asking this question, more comments were deleted, and it makes more sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What "comments" are not . . .](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not)

Comment: Please also see these other [30 questions](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bcomments%5D+deleted) asking why comments were deleted.

Comment: I see even more comments were deleted after I asked this question, so now it appears less random.

Comment: Same thing happened at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/170240/9236 except that it wasn't that some of the comments were deleted. All of them were deleted. Not moved to chat but full on deleted...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments can disappear at a moments notice, you should consider them *transient*.

Anything that does not directly seek to improve the question *can* be wiped out.  I myself don't go seeking comments to delete, typically **comments are removed due to flagging by members of the community**.

If you have something permanent for the question edit the content into the **Question**.  If you wish to answer, do so in an **Answer**.