# Inconsistent comment moderation appears capricious

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

So I had a long comment thread form under one of my trademarked "Harsh Truth" answers here:

[How can I reply to coworkers who accuse me of automating people out of work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/143021/how-can-i-reply-to-coworkers-who-accuse-me-of-automating-people-out-of-work/143023#143023)

And I notice one comment I made about being able to handle the flak was removed.  The thread makes no sense for a bit because of that.

I fully expected the moderators to push it to a chat room, but to remove a single comment appears to be "picking favorites."

Not that I'm actually hurt by it, but it really makes the moderation seem ... irregular.

Comment: I think the reason this usually happens is that your one particular comment got flagged, but none of the others, so only your comment was removed. Usually moderators don't spend too much effort sorting through the rest of the comments in every thread with a flagged comment, as that would take more time than they have.

Comment: Don't forget that users can delete their own comments and answers.  Don't assume that everything removed is because a moderator did it.

Comment: @Snow - I can assure you with the utmost certainty that I did not delete my own comment.

Comment: Thats because moderation IS irregular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did the comments go?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6188/where-did-the-comments-go)

Answer (score 13):

I cannot speak for the other moderators, but I don't go looking for comments to prune.  I am only really interested in comments *flagged by the community*.

See more details here on a similar question: [What happened to my comment(s)?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6188/where-did-the-comments-go/6189#6189)

Answer (score 9):

Speaking generally: when I see comment flags I almost always click through to see what else on the post might need attention, *but* if the comment is really egregious (like, name-calling) and I don't want to take the time to read a big pile of comments right now, I'll handle *that* flag right away.  No matter what else is going on in the comments, *that* one has to go so I delete it.  (This isn't commentary on your specific comment, which I didn't handle.)

The Workplace gets a *lot* of comments.  Flags are our guides for where the problems are brewing.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are assuming that a Mod did that.

A single comment could have been deleted if it got flagged multiple times (seems it's [3 or a bit more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/332286) if upvoted) by members of the Community (the Organic way of handling comments).

Perhaps, as it was a harsh truth, some users decided to react negatively towards the statement, and surely must have flagged it.