# Why was this answer deleted on: What are best practices for employee surveys?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/179391/59502

> There are vendors that specialize in designing and implementing employee surveys. Set up an introductory call with several of them.

The answer was deleted by Lilienthal with the note:

> On The Workplace, we're looking for answers with some depth that
> explain why and how and that are ideally backed by facts, references,
> and personal experiences. Please see Why and how are some answers
> deleted and How do I write a good answer, as well as The back it up
> rule for more details.

The answer is indeed short, but I'd also categorise it as succinct.

It's also correct. Rather than try to formulate their own process, the OP should be engaging with 3rd parties that specialise in this.

Note that the question being closed is not an invitation for the moderators to be heavy-handed. The question can be re-opened with a shift in focus.

In addition, I think the question is probably best left open. This is a classic XY problem.

Comment: I flagged that answer as “not an answer,” so I hope it was removed for that reason.  It is in no way better than a “why don’t you go Google it” answer, and demonstrates no experience with the topic.

Comment: @mxyzplk You're actually wrong. It's not a "why don't you go Google it" answer, it's a "get a 3rd party organisation to assist with this". Even if you are a survey company yourself, you should get a 3rd party to do it. Pity that author can't clarify this point.

Comment: Oh no, we’re missing a bad answer to a bad question.  If they have a better answer, they should help workshop and improve the question to get it opened and then submit their better answer.

Comment: @mxyzplk If the community deleted the answer, I have less of a problem. If the moderators decide to delete "bad" answers, as opposed to troll answers (or abusive answers etc.), then it's a bit of a slippery slope. Quite frankly, deleting bad answers is not their role.

Comment: @mxyzplk And it's not a bad answer in any case. Probably could be elaborated on, but some variation of the answer would make for a great answer.

Comment: Those flag reasons exist so mods can act on them.  It’s how the system is designed.

Comment: @mxyzplk Very mature of your to suggest I sam sad for raising the question. From Stack Exchange: "Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those exceptional conditions that could otherwise disrupt the community.". Exceptional conditions, not deleting bad answers because someone flagged it.

Comment: @mxyzplk For instance, I just flagged your comment calling me sad for being "unfriendly or unkind". Out of the listed reasons, "bad answer" is not there.

Comment: “Not an answer” is however.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP was more curious about what goes into an employee survey than setting up one. Wouldn't consulting a 3rd party firm involve some kind of payment? The deleted answer is the response to a different, perhaps implied,  specific request, what to do or where to go if you want to set up a survey in your company. I don't think the answer was "good" (it definitely lacks details), but I don't think it was so off-topic to warrant a deletion.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not Lilienthal so I obviously don't know what they were thinking but I have to say I'm not surprised the answer was deleted. As written it simply isn't any more an answer to the question than someone answering a stackoverflow question on C# with

> There are vendors that specialize in designing and implementing software in C#. Set up an introductory call with several of them.

Honestly I have to say the comment you quoted explained the situation rather well. If author of the answer believes there are significant, or even insurmountable obstacles to doing the survey process in-house then a proper answer would explain that, and *why* before suggesting contacting a third party vendor.

> The question can be re-opened with a shift in focus.

The question does need a shift - or at the very least a *narrowing* in focus before it would be suitable to re-opened IMO, as it stands it contains 3 explicit questions, all with a fairly broad scope.

Comment: I view it more as: "Any tips for developing your own crypto library?", with an answer of: "No, don't do that. Use an existing library."

Comment: For clarity, you don't involve a 3rd party because you want them to teach you, you involve them to conduct it.

Answer (score 4):

The main reason is that it's a two sentence answer that doesn't actually address the question in any meaningful way. That on its own would normally prompt me to convert it to a comment. Since it would become comment that I would also have deleted as not seeking clarification (cf [What "comments" are not . . .](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) and [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757)), that means I skip straight to deleting the answer.

The added bonus reason is that it was the sole answer posted mere minutes before the question was closed. That would prevent the question from being pruned if it was kept closed and scored negatively. It also means the poster could have seen the question was likely headed for closure and should have perhaps thought twice whether the question was suitable and therefore worth answering.

Thirdly, the post was also flagged as "very low quality", which is how I came upon it to begin with.

> The question can be re-opened with a shift in focus.

All of the above is unrelated to the merits or otherwise of the question itself. The question remaining closed or being reopened is not really relevant to whether non-answers should be cleaned up. *If* it's an XY question, any answer going that route should also make it clear by reframing the problem.

> Note that the question being closed is not an invitation for the moderators to be heavy-handed.

I don't really consider this kind of housekeeping to be overly heavy-handed. It seems in the interest of this site to try and make sure answers meet at least some bar. Answering the question asked and/or providing at least some detail if you don't doesn't seem like too high a bar at that.

Comment: It's heavy handed because I don't believe you should be using your executive rights to flat out delete answers that YOU think could be clarified. I can't even vote to reopen the answer. You should reserve that power for answers that are troll answers and let the community self-regulate.

Comment: If I think there's value in a post but it needs additional work I'll leave a comment instead. I just don't agree that two-sentence contributions like this constitute good faith answers that deserve to be kept. Short answers certainly *can* be good and comprehensive, they just usually aren't, as was the case here. If a veteran poster like this feels they have a more substantial point to make, they could simply repost a more detailed answer. Though not here of course since the question was closed. But I suspect we'll each stick with our own point of view on this one.

Comment: I actually can't believe you are suggesting Michael McFarlane's answer was not posted in good faith. But okay.

Answer (score 2):

For the question to be salvaged it will need to be much more focused. If that answer is exactly as you have quoted it, it is unlikely to answer any on-topic question here.

For example, one way to salvage the question would be to narrow it down to the pros and cons of creating the survey in-house versus outsourcing it. "Go find a third party to conduct the survey." doesn't answer that.

Another way to salvage the question might be "What are the most important factors when designing a employee survey process with the goal of improving employee retention?" The deleted answer doesn't answer that either.

The purpose of closing a question is to prevent answers while the question is brought on-topic, so yes I do think a question being closed shifts the threshold for deleting low quality answers a bit more toward "delete". If the answer was significantly more than a sentence, that might tilt the scales back toward not deleting it. Frankly, I don't think that answer is very helpful even as a comment. It doesn't explain how to find any of these companies; it just states something that is fairly obvious (such companies exist).

Comment: It's not that obvious to be fair.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Really? I mean a *lot* of employees in corporate America have taken an employee survey that was conducted by a different company. Even if someone hasn't heard of a third party survey vendor, how helpful is "they exist, go find one"?

Comment: What has corporate America got to do with this?