# Can someone tell me why my comments were deleted?

Tags: support

My comments were deleted on this Workplace question:

[How to politely stop a colleague's rude remarks about the way I sip alcohol?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/185537/how-to-politely-stop-a-colleagues-rude-remarks-about-the-way-i-sip-alcohol)

I suspect it was due to bad language, but I can't be sure. Can someone with elevated permissions tell me what happened?

Comment: They were likely flagged as not being necessary.  Why are you using offensive vulgarity?  Moderator explained what happen, the unnecessary commentary, was moved to a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137041/discussion-on-question-by-the-great-how-to-politely-stop-a-colleagues-rude-rema).  The vulgarity likely was deleted before this migration happened otherwise it would have been flagged for removal within the chat. [Mod Explaination](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/185537/how-to-politely-stop-a-colleagues-rude-remarks-about-the-way-i-sip-alcohol#comment608374_185537)

Comment: @Donald I don't think I said anything offsensive, I certainly didn't intend to!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I deleted the comments as they were not asking the OP for clarification or anything like that and I wanted to keep the comment thread within a reasonable size.

I deleted 18 other comments as well on the same thread for the same reason during the day. Nothing to do with vulgarity. I don't see anything particularly wrong with your comments themselves, they just weren't needed. They were better suited as part of an answer perhaps.

Comments built up again and another mod moved them to chat in a separate action some hours later.

Comment: That makes sense thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not the mod who removed your two comments, however I can see that both were flagged by the community and removed at some point prior to the chat migration.

The vulgarity (although censored) may have played a part , as may have been the fact that the two combined comments were clearly an attempted **answer** to the question.
Now that's [not what comments are for](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not), we have a whole "answer" section dedicated for just such purposes.

While I'm not going around looking for answers-in-comments to terminate with any sort of prejudice if they get flagged with a "no longer needed" they're probably going to get removed, if they're exceeding the length of the comment box such that it needs multiple comments they're probably going to get removed, if they're even *remotely* flirting with vulgarity they're probably going to get removed.

Like I say I'm not out hunting for ones to remove - but that doesn't change that comments on Stack Exchange sites are intended to be largely ephemeral, so generally it's not advisable to get too attached to them.

Comment: Makes sense, cheers.